# Python QDateEdit increment

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, qdate

I'm using a QDateEdit control in a GUI in Python. I want to control it just by using keyboard, so when I press the up arrow key it changes from 31-jan-2000 to 01-feb-2000, by instance.

Currently, it just changes year, month and day independiently, but I want to change it like a block, increasing by calendar days.

In the gif, you could see the behavior of the control, I changed day, month and year independently, but I couldn't change it as a "whole date".

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Ok, show us what you did so far....

Comment: I put a gif to show you what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible override the default behaviour by reimplementing `stepBy`:

```
class DateEdit(QtGui.QDateEdit):    
    def stepBy(self, steps):
        self.setDateTime(self.dateTime().addDays(steps))
```

However, this doesn't *quite* work perfectly, because the cursor **must** be in the *year section* to get continuous increments. If it's in the *month section*, it will only increment through all months/days in the year; and if it's in the *day section*, it will only increment through all days in the month. Personally, I think I would treat this as a "feature", and leave it at that (since the implementaion is so simple).

You could try to force the cursor to stay in the *year section*, but that would prevent manual editing, which significantly reduces usability. However, I suppose you could use the calendar-popup to provide manual editing, and then make the line-edit read-only:

```
class DateEdit(QtGui.QDateEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DateEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCalendarPopup(True)
        edit = self.lineEdit()
        edit.setReadOnly(True)
        edit.selectionChanged.connect(lambda edit=edit: edit.end(False))

    def stepBy(self, steps):
        self.setDateTime(self.dateTime().addDays(steps))
```